# bootstrap alert if else

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to use bt alerts for  'status' and 'name' alterations, it works but after refresh(F5)  alert is still visible.

//saving alert as var

```
$_alrtOk ='<div class="alert alert-success text-center" role="alert"> 
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">       
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
 Editado!</div>';
```

//and my code

```
if(isset($_POST['blqAtiv'])){
//if status updates - alert success
$mysqli->query("UPDATE colaboradores SET status='$blqAtiv' WHERE   id='$id'");

 echo $_alrtOk;
//if name changed - aler success
}else if(isset($_POST['name'])){

$mysqli->query("UPDATE colaboradores SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id'");

echo $_alrtOk;
}
```

//updated code

```
<?php
@$alert = $_POST['alert'];
@$id = $_POST['idAl'];
@$blqAtiv = $_POST['blqAtiv'];

$result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM alertas WHERE   alert='$alert'");
$row = $result_set->fetch_assoc();
$row_cnt = $result_set->num_rows;

if($row_cnt >= 1){

}else{

   if(isset($_POST['blqAtiv'])){
   $mysqli->query("UPDATE alertas SET status='$blqAtiv' WHERE id='$id'");
   echo $_alrAlter;

   }else if(isset($_POST['alert'])){

    if (!empty($row['id'])) {

    }else{
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE alertas SET alert='$alert' WHERE  id='$id'");
          echo $_alrtOk;
        }
          }
       }
     ?>
```

and i got this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J8Qm.jpg)

Comment: The browser asks you if you want to submit the form again on refresh, right? You submit your form again on refresh, that's why the if condition is still true

Comment: yes browser ask to submit, how can i fix it?if i use only 1 alert it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you resubmitting the form when reloading? If yes, that's the issue, I also faced it once when dealing with form data.
Try reopening the browser too.

Comment: nope reopening does not help,only direct refresh from address line(Enter). How did u fix it?

Comment: This is a know issue, you can know more here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
You can add some javascript to show the alert for a few seconds than hide it, also resetting the post variable at the end of your code like this ->

$_POST = array();

Answer (score 0):

Resolution: header( "Refresh:5; url=http://www.example.com/page2.php", true, 303); and if you use x2 Post/Get make sure what you gave them unique names.